# How do I delete a Managed Package that is developed in a Dev Org

Tags: managed-package, developer-edition, delete-managed-package

I have a custom application developed in my Dev Org and created a **Managed Package** for it. But now I want to delete this from my Org.

When I'm trying to do so, it is throwing a message as **This Package cannot be deleted because it has the following uploaded versions:**.

So, how could I come across this and delete the **Managed Package**.

Comment: Is your Package publically exposed ? If yes, i think thats why you are getting this error.

Comment: @KawSumit yes it is but that package is created for testing purpose. Moreover,is there a way I could delete it and I also raised a ticket to enable "Deprecate" button for the latest version of the Package.